# How to delete all messages in a bot chat so that Start appears?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Is there any library or code that will help delete all messages at the end of the dialogue with the bot?
P.S. I know that you can use: `bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id)` but there are a lot of messages and it’s hard to catch them by each id. Perhaps someone can suggest a magic cycle to go through all chat messages and delete them? Maybe there is an interesting library with such functionality?

`bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id)`